# How to pass dynamic values in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I really don't know how to properly title this questions so sorry for possible confusion. Here is my problem. I have a JSON file with two arrays.

```
{
    "list 1": 
    [
        {
            "name": "label1",
            "imgPath": "images/list1img1.png"
        },

        {
            "name": "label2",
            "imgPath": "images/list1img2.png"
        },
    ]

    "list 2": 
    [
        {
            "name": "label1",
            "imgPath": "images/list12img1.png"
        },

        {
            "name": "label2",
            "imgPath": "images/list2img2.png"
        },
    ]
}
```

I also have a html file with two texts and an image container:

```
<h2>list 1</h2>
<h2>list 2</h2>

<div class="container"></div>
```

I want to click a list and load images from JSON file into container using Jquery. I have managed to make a function that does this but here is when I get stuck.

```
$document.ready(function () {
    $(h2).click(function(e) {
        loadJson(e);
    }       
});

function loadJson(e) {

        var jsonURL = "images.json";

        var txt = $(e.target).text(); // text from h2 element, it can be list1 or list2

        $.getJSON(jsonURL, function (json)
        {
            var imgList= "";

            $.each(json.#################, function () {
                imgList += '<img src="' + this.imgPath + '"/>';
            });
            $('.container').append(imgList);
        });
    }
```

the code is working but I want to put txt variable (that essentially gets the name of JSON array)  where I put those hashes.

Comment: have a look at `Object.keys(...)`.

Comment: this would do : `$.each(json[txt]` use `[]`

Comment: @orglce You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to use `[]` to pass dynamic values

```
 $.each(json[txt], function () {
       imgList += '<img src="' + this.imgPath + '"/>';
 });
```

This would fetch only the `list 1` values

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON(jsonURL, function (json)
    {
        var imgList= "";
       $.each(json[txt], function () {
            imgList += '<img src="' + this.imgPath + '"/>';
        });
        $('.container').append(imgList);
    });
}
```

You can put put txt variable inside `[]` tag . Hope it will work